# Como instalar o Laravel 5 sem usar composer?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Existe alguma maneira de instalar o Laravel 5, sem a utilização do Composer?

Acho que na versão 4 tinha uma forma onde não precisava do Composer, mas parece que o 5 agora está "mais dependente com composer".

Comment: Alguma sugestão de melhoria à minha pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, o ideal é você instalar via Composer, pois todos os arquivos necessários serão baixados.
Entretanto, pode baixar os arquivos pelo GitHub (https://github.com/laravel/laravel), mas ainda vai precisar instalar as dependência via Composer.

Comment: Realmente, parece que a opção de fazer download é coisa de Laravel 3 e afins. Via na documentaçao do [4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation) que era possível fazer download, mas tinha que usar composer. Agora parece que composer é realmente um requisito do Laravel. +1